# There is an extra "[]" in the json I created. How can I remove them?

Tags: python, json, database

I print the data I pull from the database as json. But there is an extra "[]" character when printing. How can I remove them or how

```
sql = """select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(a))) from(select * from games) a ;  """
cur.execute(sql)
print("Data extracting...")
a=cur.fetchall()
print(a)
with open('mongo.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(a,outfile,indent=4)
    print("Json file created")
```

---output---

```
[
    [
        [
            {"x":"2",
"y":"2"
}

]
]
]
```

Comment: please provide a more descriptiveness in your question.

Comment: I don't know technical spec of `array_to_json()` if it returns a list of result sets that's why you will get a 3d list.   if you just want first reurned result set then `json.dump(a[0],outfile,indent=4)`.  Beware for `IndexError` and behaviour is what you expect

Answer (score 0):

It is not an extra [], but the closing brackets

copy paste your json here:
[Json Formatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

```
[
   [
      [
         {
            "x":"2",
            "y":"2"
         }
      ]
   ]
]
```

Comment: I want to remove two block brackets. 
just get 1 "[]"

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remove just outer brackets. I think you need that:

```
a = [[[{'x': '2', 'y': '2'}]]]  # your response
a = list(*a)  # here you'll get [[{'x': '2', 'y': '2'}]]
```

Comment: Or you can go just inside lists by

`a = a[0][0]  # [{'x': '2', 'y': '2'}]`